# Ejecutar función en segundo plano

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un temporizador que cuenta el tiempo que llevas de descanso en javascript/jquery. El problema es que cuando el teléfono se pone en suspensión, la pagina se pone el 2 plano y la alarma no suena cuando el temporizador llega a su minuto indicado.
Hay alguna forma para solucionar esto? Pongo el código para que os hagais una mejor idea.

```
function tiempoTicado(fecha,audio,org){


const myDatetime = fecha;
const splitString = myDatetime.split(" ");//Se separa la cadena a partir del espacio entre la fecha y la hora
const splitDate = splitString[0].split("/");//Se separan los elementos de la fecha
const splitTime = splitString[1].split(":");//Se separan los elementos de la hora
//Con los elementos separados, y para tener más orden y claridad, se puede asignar cada valor a variables cuyos nombres sean fáciles de identificar.
//Enseguida, tendrás que restarle una unidad al valor del mes, esto debido a que el objeto Date de JavaScript trabaja con los meses de una manera similar a como lo hacen los arreglos y sus índices; es decir, empezando por el cero, lo cual quiere decir que, por ejemplo, el mes dado como 6, será interpretado como el séptimo. Asimismo, como el formato de la fecha es de cuatro dígitos, tendrás que completar la parte faltante. Esto puedes hacerlo concatenando el 20 con el valor de la variable del año.
const day = splitDate[0]; //EL dia
const month = splitDate[1] - 1;//El mes
const year = `20${splitDate[2]}`;//El año
const hours = splitTime[0];
const minutes = splitTime[1];
//Ya con todos los valores separados y formateados, puedes construir un objeto de fecha:
const finalDatetime = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes);
const realDatetime = new Date(); //La fecha y hora del sistema
//Finalmente, solo quedará realizar la resta de forma directa y dividir el resultado, dado en milésimas de segundo, entre el producto de 60 por 1000, esto debido a que se requiere transformar las milésimas de segundo a segundos y estos a minutos. Además de ello, puedes usar la función parseInt() para que el resultado mostrado no contenga la parte decimal:
var diff = Math.abs(finalDatetime - realDatetime);
var segundos = pad(Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60));
var minutos = pad(Math.floor((diff / (1000 * 60)) % 60));


if(org==2){
    
    if(minutos>19){
        audio.play();
        
    }
    
    /*if((minutos==19)&&(segundos==30)){
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
    }*/
    
}



var horas = pad(Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)));
$("#tiempo").text(horas +":"+minutos+":"+segundos);
```

}

A esta función se la llama cada segundo con un interval, Este código funciona correctamente cuando vuelves a entrar en la web, te vuelve a calcular el tiempo y si se da la condición ejecuta el audio.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Has pensado en utilizar programación reactiva para manejar de manera más efectiva flujos de eventos de forma asíncrona o implementar RxJS? Creo que async/await y Promises pueden no resolverlo porque javascript no ejecutará el código mientras la página esté inactiva.